# Is unlock guard (or boost::reverse_lock) a anti-pattern? Why?

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking

Is there known issues related to unlock guards:

```
 unique_lock<mutex> lock(smtx); 

 // ... 

 { // non locked block 
     reverse_lock< unique_lock<mutex> > rlock(lock); 

     // ...
 } // locked again 

 // ...
```

that could make this generally an anti-pattern?

It was suggested that it should be avoided in one of my code reviews, without clear explanation why.

Comment: I personally would have two locked scopes but that is just how I would style it.

Comment: You probably should ask the reviewer. I personally belive that locks should be held for shortest possible time and locking should be as predictable as possible. Breaking lock in-between adds a certain upredictability to it. But I have no idea what was the actual code being reviewed, possibly it was approriate there...

Comment: I do not use it all the time, and definitely not if it could be easily avoided. But there some cases where loops or other RAII objects are involved that make the code easier to write

Comment: @SergeyA I did, but no answer so far. Also, I prefer to double check such things myself, and since I did not find any article in the net on the topic, I think the stackoverflow community is good option too.

Comment: @gsf, there are different levels of checks. If someone tells you something is wrong, an exact description of what is wrong should always accompany it.

Comment: @SergeyA It was not like "this is wrong" more of "we prefer to avoid it", but it still made me thinking.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's an anti pattern. While I would prefer scoped locking when possible, with condition variables it is not easy to use pure scoped locking.

I use the reverese_lock for these cases:

```
void WorkQueue::Run()
{
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lck(m_mtxQueue);

    for (;;)
    {
        // wait for an item to be pushed
        while (m_deqItems.empty())
        {
            m_cvAvailable.wait(lck);
        }

        // signal worker thread(s) to process items
        if (!m_deqItems.empty())
        {
            Item item = m_deqItems.front();
            m_deqItems.pop_front();


            // unlock during (lengthy) processing of an item
            boost::reverse_lock<boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>> unlck(lck);

            ProcessItem(item);
        }
    }
}
```